# Nested CSS in GWT 2.5

Tags: css, gwt

lets start off with the statement, this is the first UI I have built in over 7 years.  I don't remember anything about them, and was never any good at them back then.  I'm a middleware guy so I'm learning everything over again with this stuff.

I'm trying to build a cssresource bundle in GWT 2.5.  My UX guy gave me this css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body { min-height: 100%; }
a { text-decoration: none; }

.mainheader {
  background: linear-gradient(#3F94BF, #246485);
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #222 0px -1px 1px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

.pagewrap {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

.mainnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3B3B3B;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
  a {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #383838);
    border-top: 1px solid #484848;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      background: linear-gradient(#484848, #383838);
    }
  }
  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(black, 0), rgba(black, 0.4));
  }
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.closemenu {
  display: none;
}

#mainnav:target {
  width: 20%;
}
#mainnav:target + .pagewrap {
  width: 80%;
  .open-menu {
     display: none; 
  }
  .closemenu {
     display: block;
  }
  .mainheader {
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

Now when i put that in, i get the following errors:

```
    [DEBUG] [myapp] - Rebinding nope.gwt.client.resources.ITRResources
    [DEBUG] [myapp] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
        [DEBUG] [myapp] - Preparing method css
            [INFO] [myapp] - The following problems were detected
                [WARN] [myapp] - Line 20 column 4: encountered "{". Was expecting one of: ":" 
                [WARN] [myapp] - Line 43 column 4: encountered "{". Was expecting one of: ":" 
                [WARN] [myapp] - Line 49 column 19: encountered "&". Was expecting one of: "}" ";" <IDENT> 
                [WARN] [myapp] - Line 77 column 14: encountered ".". Was expecting one of: "}" ";" <IDENT> 
[DEBUG] [myapp] - Rebinding nope.gwt.client.uibinder.SearchPanel.SearchPanelUiBinder
    [DEBUG] [myapp] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
        [ERROR] [myapp] - The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
        [ERROR] [myapp] - Error parsing XML (line 35): The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
[ERROR] [myapp] - Deferred binding failed for 'nope.gwt.client.uibinder.SearchPanel.SearchPanelUiBinder'; expect subsequent failures
[DEBUG] [myapp] - Rebinding com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImpl
    [WARN] [myapp] - For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
        [WARN] [myapp] - nope.gwt.client.uibinder.SearchPanel_SearchPanelUiBinderImpl
[ERROR] [myapp] - Unable to load module entry point class nope.gwt.client.myapp (see associated exception for details)
[ERROR] [myapp] - Failed to load module 'myapp' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.48 Safari/537.36' at 127.0.0.1:50211
```

I can't tell if im binding something wrong or if my css isn't any good.

here's my resource interface

```
public interface ITRcss extends CssResource {
    String content();

    String pagewrap();

    String mainheader();

    String mainnav();

    String closemenu();

}
```

and my client bundle

```
public interface ITRResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final ITRResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(ITRResources.class);

    @Source("itr.css")
    public ITRcss css();

    // @Source("config.xml")
    // public TextResource initialConfiguration();
    //
    // @Source("manual.pdf")
    // public DataResource ownersManual();
}
```

Comment: Ask your "UX guy" but this is not CSS (might be SASS or LESS or something similar)

Comment: you were right.  it was SASS.  He gave me equiv css and I was able to figure out how to run interface generator and get it to build the skeleton.    Thanks